# How to run test one by one rather than parallel using maven?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have several test case in one Test class, and I want to run these test case one by one (seems by default they would run parallelly). I use maven-surefire-plugin, is there any option for that ? thanks

Comment: It is not parallelly , how did you get such a conclusion

Answer (score 0):

> Defines the order the tests will be run in. 
>   Supported values are "alphabetical", "reversealphabetical", "random", "hourly" (alphabetical on even hours, reverse alphabetical on odd hours), "failedfirst", "balanced" and "filesystem".

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.17</version>
  <configuration>
    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
  </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

[Documentation Here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder)